# Prevent Ajax load from loading src more than once

Tags: jquery, ajax, loading

I am loading a bunch of LIs into an HTML page via Ajax load (code below for the call), this works fine, but after the HTML page of LIs has been loaded in, it seems it calls the same HTML source another 4 times all at once and messes everything up... what am I doing wrong???

```
$.ajax({
cache: false,
url: 'slides.html',
success: function(data) {



         JWLoadInitialSlider();

         $(this).show();

         $(".sliderLoader").fadeOut(3000);

         setTimeout(function(){
         $(".carouselContentWrapper").css("height","auto");
         }, 2000);




}
});
```

Is there a way to kill this function once it has loaded and performed the success functions?

Comment: do you have the other part of the code? where that ajax is called from?

Comment: This JS snipped (as above) is just called inline in the HTML to pull in the data from slides.html (which is just loads of <li></li> data)

Comment: if you put alert("something"); before the ajax, and another alert("funcion success"); inside the success function what happend? how many alerts are you getting?, is strange, if you are calling that ajax inline, it should only be executeded 1 time. is strange that $(this).show() you have there, usualy you use $(this). when are inside a function called from an event listener like $(".div").click(etc etc

Comment: With an alert in the success function I see it first once the initial load is complete - this works well (I am watching the source HTML being loaded in Firebug), then once that alert is OKed then page then loads x4 more versions of the slides.html file... each time the new version loads I again see the loaded alert... seems that once the success function is called it then calls the load function again....

Comment: deleting everything inside the success function what happends?

Comment: it seems its the JWLoadInitialSlider(); function which messing things up - that function basically creates a version of BXSlider...

Comment: you could move that slideer function to other side. Or let me ask you, why don't you include the LIs html with php or asp? directly ?

Comment: slides LIs need to be loaded dynamically as I have code to filter the contents of them...When you say move it to the other side what do you mean?

Comment: I have a better solution, I will write it as anwser

Comment: OK - interested to have a look

Answer (score 0):

outside the ajax call define a variable

```
var SlideLoaded = "no";
```

then inside the ajax success function do this:

```
if(SlideLoaded=="no"){
  SlideLoaded = "yes";
  JWLoadInitialSlider();
}
```

so what way, if the ajax call is called more times it won't call the slider thing again.

Comment: that would obviously do the trick, but the more interesting Q is, why is it repeatedly calling the AJAX function. Workarounds like this tend to move the problem to another place instead of actually solving it.

Comment: Appreciate the approach but it doesnt work - the ajax load function is called 4 more times following initial load success...

Comment: Is there a better way to load in via Ajax? $('.bxslider').load("slides.html"); seems to work well - but I cant see how to add the JWLoadInitialSlider(); on load sucess ?

Comment: if with the workarrund the problem persists, then the JWLoadInitialSlider function is not the problem, can you add an alert("something") after Slideloaded = "yes"; and see if it alerts 4 times also?

Comment: Think the issue is the Ajax load call - just tried using $('.bxslider').load("slides.html", function(){
alert("load success");
JWLoadInitialSlider();
// fade out loader div
$(".sliderLoader").fadeOut(3000);

}); and works now!